# stopping an attached thread asynchrously using ptrace - linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, debugging, asynchronous, ptrace

after attaching a pthread using its pid and manipulating the content of its debug registers, while waiting using waitpid(-1, &status, __WALL) ; I would like to be able to stop that thread and make additional manipulations (defining another breakpoint etc).

when I try sending a signal using kill() and waiting for the thread to be ready for additional ptrace requests, for just one target thread, it works fine. on the other hand, when the number of traced threads increase, i got stuck within waitpid() call and never get unblocked.

is there a safe and fast mechanism to stop an attached thread that is running for additional modifications?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When sending a signal to a thread, do not use the `pid`. Sending a signal to a process (which is what you are doing) sends it to some random thread within that process, which is almost certainly not what you would like to do. The tool to send threads signals is `ptrhread_kill`.

That's where things become a little more hairy. The `ptrace` interface uses "thread ID" (or `tid`). These are framed in the same context as process IDs, i.e. - integers. `pthread_kill`, on the other hand, uses the `pthread_t` type, which is an opaque, and is not the same thing.

Since using `ptrace` means you are in dark magic land already, the simplest solution is to use `tgkill`. Just place your `tid` and `pid` in the relevant fields, and you're golden.

Of course, `tgkill` is not an exported function. You'll need to wrap it in `syscall` in order to invoke it.